# How do I quote a graphic novel?

Tags: citations, mla

I am writing a paper for a Canadian Literature class, and want to quote portions of one of the graphic novels we studied. Do I quote the written portions as I would any other written work? I am using MLA, so would it be like (Author,Page), like a conventional book? Or are there other conventions for graphic novels that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 6):

The MLA has a section on graphic novels. Basically, you cite the source in the same way as a regular non-periodical publication. If it's a single author, yes, you would use (Author, Page) format. See the [Purdue OWL online writing lab](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/01/) for details on MLA format. See also this [site](http://elmo.academyart.edu/reference-help/mla_citation_guide.html#graphic) for specific information on how to form graphic novel citations in your Works Cited Page. As far as I know, you can't peruse the entire MLA manual online for free.

Comment: Good answer. I would also point out that graphic novels can be treated as general works with often more than one author (i.e. writer and artist)